# How to use Vision toolkit in labVIEW?

Tags: labview

We have a 16-bit image and trying to process that image using Vision module LabVIEW 2010. Is 16-bit image possible to process in Vision toolkit ?
We are buying Biomedical Toolkit for LabVIEW 2014, We are not aware of processing 16-bit images in that toolkit.

When I am opening and saving the 16-bit tiff image, intensity values of image are varied 10 times of original image intensity ( example: from 3,200 to 35,000). Why it is happening. I have attached screen shots of small code and inverse help context.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll address only one of your questions:
yes, NI Vision Development Module  can process 16-bit images.

I'll suggest to give a look here, too:
[16-bit Images in NI Vision](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/80FFFCBBCF30B34B862574440014BCD8)

Regards,
Marco